# Plot all values against their respective medians

Tags: r, boxplot, median

I have a large dataframe for which I computed the median per row. To keep things simple, this is my dataframe

```
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(c(1,2,3),c(2,2,5),c(5,4,5),c(5,6,5),c(2,6,6)))
df$median = apply(df, 1, median, na.rm=T)
df
  V1 V2 V3 median
1  1  2  3      2
2  2  2  5      2
3  5  4  5      5
4  5  6  5      5
5  2  6  6      6
```

Now I want to make boxplots of all values against their respective median. So there would be an x-axis with median 2, 5 and 6 and all the values from which the median was calculated on the y-axis.

I am very new to R and have no clue how to go about this. I made a plot with a cheat dataframe to illustrate what I want:

```
df2 <- cbind(c(1,2,3,2,2,5),c(5,4,5,5,6,5),c(4,6,6))
colnames(df2) <- c("2","5","6")

df2
     2 5 6
[1,] 1 5 4
[2,] 2 4 6
[3,] 3 5 6
[4,] 2 5 4
[5,] 2 6 6
[6,] 5 5 6

boxplot(df2, xlab="median")
```

[image]

How can I achieve this with code? As you can see, the third column has its values duplicated as there are less values corresponding to median 6. This is certainly true for my real dataframe as well so this is definitely not the way to do it.

Any help or suggestions are welcome!

Comment: For me, that doesn't make sense. Usally the boxplot shows the median and you don't put it on the x-axis. In your case, based on `df`, I would create a boxplot for every row, putting the row number on the x-axis and the values on the y-axis.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I agree it might be a non-intuitive way of plotting. My real dataframe is a bit larger (6000 rows) so I would really like to group the data by respective median to get less boxplots.

Comment: If two rows are resulting in the same median, how would the plot look like? Do you want multiple box plots with the same median or do you want one box plot for the combined data?

Comment: One boxplot for each median irrespective of how many values/observations have led to this median. So if I have 3 unique medians, I want 3 boxplots. I'd like to know how to even start doing this. My guess was that I need to subset my data per median, make seperate boxplots and combine them in ggplot. Does that sound sensical to yo?

Comment: That sounds good. But what happens if you don't have unique medians?

Comment: My real dataframe has 6000 rows and 22 unique medians.

Comment: Added a new version. Perhaps this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a way to box plot your data based on my comment:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=c(-median, -id)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=id, y=value, group=id)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

gives you

[image]

**Edit**

Based on your comments I think you could use

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=c(-median)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=median, y=value, group=median)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

instead of the code shown above which returns this plot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be what you want to do.

```
stk <- data.frame(stack(df[, 1:3]), median=df$median)
```

This will produce a boxplot like your picture, but median 6 will only be based on 3 values:

```
table(stk$median)
# 
# 2 5 6 
# 6 6 3
```

It may be more informative to use a strip chart:

```
stripchart(values~median, stk, method="stack", xlab="median", vert=TRUE)
```

[image: Strip chart]

Comment: Thank you for your handy ```stack``` function. This is very close to what I need. I am trying t use it now to extract all rows in my dataframe that result in the same value for median and make boxplots seperately.